# grok filter for logstash

Tags: logstash, syslog, grok

My log file has lines of the form:

```
10/13 14:05:18.192 [modulename]: [pid]: (debug level string): message string XYZ:<xyz value>
```

where

- `modulename` is a string
- `pid` is an integer number
- `debug level string` is a string like "debug" or "info" or "error"
- `message string` is a string
- `xyz value` is an integer number

example:

```
10/13 14:05:18.192 [MyModule]: [12345]: (debug): This is my message. XYZ: 987
```

I searched around and tried a few things, but am getting `_grokparsefailure`. Can someone help show me what filter I can use in logstash to parse these logs?

Comment: What have you tried?  And have you tried using http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to incrementally add to your pattern?

Comment: If I give above example log to Discover in the grokdebugger, it suggests: %{SYSLOGPROG}{URIPATHPARAM} %{HAPROXYTIME} %{SYSLOG5424SD}: %{NAGIOSTIME}: (debug): This is my message. XYZ: 987 , but when I use Debugger link in grokdebugger and use this pattern and give my example input, it does not like it. Also, seems grokdebugger is treating 10/13 as pathname? and pid as NAGIOSTIME - doesn't seem right.

Comment: `(?<date>\d\d/\d\d) %{TIME:time} \[%{WORD:module}\]: \[%{WORD:pid}\]:` matches the beginning of your log... see if you can finish it

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I am not able to parse 987 (my example above) into an integer. I tried: (?<date>\d\d/\d\d) %{TIME:time} \[%{WORD:module}\]: \[%{WORD:pid}\]: \(%{WORD:dbg_lvl}\): %{GREEDYDATA:msg} XYZ: %{INT:count} but I get parse error. If I remove XYZ: %{INT:count} it works but then I lose count. Also, I'd like to combine date and time so I can sort it by date+time. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `{GREEDYDATA}` means until the end of a logging event. So, all the text that resides after `dbg_lvl` will be assigned to `{GREEDYDATA}`

Here, try the following code. The problem with your code filter was it was not able to parse anything after `msg`. Hope this helps.

`(?<date>\d\d/\d\d) %{TIME:time} \[%{WORD:module}\]: \[%{WORD:pid}\]: \(%{WORD:log_level}\): %{CISCO_REASON}. %{WORD}: %{BASE10NUM:xyz_number}`

Comment: It works for most part. But I've noticed that whenever message string has characters like [] or ! or ... or aaa.bbb.ccc, the parsing fails. Where can I find definition of CISCO_REASON and other inbuilt parsers I can use? Basically I want to be able to parse logs with any string between log_lvl: and XYZ: .